# How to make SharePoint Dialog Box responsive?

Tags: dialog, sharepoint-2013

I am opening SharePoint dialog using following code:

```
var options = {
            title: dialogTitle,
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            url: uri
        }
        SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
```

However, the dimensions are in pixels. Is there any way to make the Pop-up responsive?